# Speed up cross validated random forest approach by parallel computing

Tags: r

I'm trying to speed up my random forest approach by parallel computing. My dataset contains of 20.000 rows and 10 columns. Dependent variable, which could be predicted, is a numerical and there are two factors between independent variables (one has 2 levels and second one has 504 levels).

I think the function train does coding all the factor variables into dummy variables, so decoding is not needed in this case.

Please, could you give me some useful advice, how to speed up the following code, I would appreciate any of advice. The solution below is never ending. Thanks a lot in advance.

```
library(doParallel); library(caret)

set.seed(975)
forTraining <- createDataPartition(DATA$NumVar,
                               p = 3/4)[[1]]
trainingSet <- DATA[forTraining,]
testSet <- DATA[-forTraining,]

controlObject <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                          repeats = 5,
                          number = 10)
#run model in parallel
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
registerDoParallel(cl)

set.seed(669)
rfModel <- train(NumVar ~ .,
             data = trainingSet,
             method = "rf",
             tuneLength = 10,
             ntrees = 1000,
             importance = TRUE,
             trControl = controlObject)
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: How long have you been waiting?  You can set `verboseIter = TRUE` in the `trainControl` function to see that the tuning is running and its' progress.  You are fitting a large model with a large number of trees and several iterations.  It is likely going to take a while.

Comment: I've been waiting for 6 hours and then I terminated it... I was wondering, if I try to change repeatedcv to cv and remove repeats from trainControl, it shoud be faster. There must exist another approach to speed up this stuff...

Comment: Thank you for verboseIter = TRUE setting, I didn't know it before. Now it seems to work very long :-)

Comment: Yes, changing to `cv` should make the analysis faster.  You probably could also likely decrease the number of trees as there is diminishing returns as you continue to increase.  See this [publication](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/230766583_How_Many_Trees_in_a_Random_Forest/file/d912f5040fb35357a1.pdf) for some research.

Comment: Thank you so much I'll check it. Optimal number of trees in R you can check by NoTrees <- randomForest(dependentVariable ~ ., data = dataSet, mtry = 522, ntree=3000, importance=TRUE, do.trace=100) with the minimal of OOB. Do you happen to know, if there is any interesting article to find an optimal number of trees with r implementation? What I attached is very slow too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My response is too verbose for a comment so hopefully I can help guide you.  Here is a summary of the points in the comments above.

1. Our primary concern - **Computation Time**
2. One major limitation on randomforest computation - **Number of Trees**

The general idea is that as you increase the number trees, your randomforest model will improve (i.e. lower error).  However, this increase in performance will diminish as you continue to add trees whereas computation time will continue to increase.  As such, you reach a point of diminishing returns.  So, **how to do we determine how many trees to use?**

Well, naively we could simply fit the randomForest model with the call you provide.  Another option is to do cross-validation on `ntree` but that isn't implemented by default in `caret` and Max Kuhn (the author) really knows his stuff when it comes to predictive models.  So, to get started you are on the correct track with your call you provided above:

```
randomForest(dependentVariable ~ ., data = dataSet, mtry = 522, ntree=3000, importance=TRUE, do.trace=100)
```

But let's make this reproducible and use the `mlbench` `Sonar` dataset.

```
library(mlbench)
data(Sonar)
```

But we currently don't care about variable importance at the moment so let's remove that.  Also, your `ntree` is way too high to start.  I would be surprised if you need it that high in the end.  Starting at a lower level we have the following:

```
set.seed(825)
rf1 <- randomForest(Class~., data=Sonar, mtry=3, ntree=200, do.trace=25)

> rf1 <- randomForest(Class~., data=Sonar, mtry=3, ntree=200, do.trace=25)
ntree      OOB      1      2
   25:  16.83% 11.71% 22.68%
   50:  18.27% 12.61% 24.74%
   75:  17.31% 17.12% 17.53%
  100:  15.38% 12.61% 18.56%
  125:  15.38% 10.81% 20.62%
  150:  16.35% 13.51% 19.59%
  175:  15.87% 10.81% 21.65%
  200:  14.42%  8.11% 21.65%
```

As you can see, the OOB is bottoming out at approximately 100 trees.  However, if I am uncertain or if the OOB is still dropping significantly I could run the call again with a larger number of trees.  Once you have a working number of trees, then you can tune your `mtry` with `caret::training`.

If you do end up needing to use lots of trees (i.e. 1000's) then your code is likely going to be slow.  If you have access to machines that have many processors and large amounts of RAM then your parallel implementation can help but on more common machines it will be slow going.

Comment: That sounds good. I think that's good prior investigation before applying train function. I have to use train function, because in one factor in the model I have 504 levels and randomForest is able to use only 53 levels. Train function recode factor levels into dummy variables and then compute estimates.

Comment: Do you happen to know if there is any limit for mtry in trainControl function. If I set something like mtry=seq(1,100,by =2) it would be faster, because each fold escalates to higher values (applied by number = 10 in trainControl) of mtry and eg.in 10 number in 01 fold is tested mtry=568, which is unnecessary.

Comment: `mtry` is the number of variables randomly sampled as candidates at each split. As such, the maximum is the number of variables in your dataset.  In this case you state that you have 10 columns, assuming your dependent variable is within your dataset, the maximum possible `mtry = 9`.  This is the default, creating your own grid is required if you want it more fine tuned than the default of `trainControl`.

Comment: I think this assumption of mtry=k-1, where k is a count of predictors, isn't correct. If function train recodes levels of factor to dummy variable and I have one factor of 504 levels, I suppose to have 513 variables for cross validation computing. Am I right?

Comment: Ah, I overlooked the dummy variables component.  You are correct that you would have more variables then.  However, most of my previous comment stands.  `trainControl` will only do the grid of `mtry` so fine.  If you want a more refined tuning with many more `mtry` you need to create the grid manually.

Comment: And could you help me with this grid construction for this particular dataset, please. I'm not deep familiar with this caret solution.

Comment: In your case it is quite simple. Since you are only tuning one parameter, just create a dataframe of the desired `mtry` levels (e.g. `grid = data.frame(mtry=c(2,5,10,15))`) and set `tuneGrid` equal to it within the `train` function.  If more parameters, then look into `expand.grid`.

Comment: Ok, perfect. That's helps me a lot, thank you for that. And maybe the last question. Do you know, how should I extract prediction of each tree? If I set ntrees = 1000, so how could I extract prediction of each tree with caret train function?

Comment: If I use randomForest function I can use:
pred.rf <- predict(rf.train.fit, predict.all=TRUE, newdata = dataSet)
pred.rf.int <- apply(pred.rf$individual

So how could I do similar stuff with carret's train function?

Comment: Currently you cannot pass additional parameters through caret's `predict` function.  So, you will need to extract the best parameter from the caret tuning object (whatever you set = to `train(...)` with `fit$bestTune`, refit with randomForest (on the training dataset) and use the randomForest `predict`.

Comment: Yes, that I was afraid of :-) No matter, that's also a good solution. Thank you very much for your help and your time, you help me a lot.